# App crashed when download from playstore

Tags: android

My application is in google play store, before there is no problem but from recently when I downloaded my app from play store after installation and I opened it the app crashed. I killed the app and relaunched it. It worked properly. I didn't understand why it crashed the first time when app was installed from play store. Please any suggest and provide solution for this. Thanks very much.

Error Message

```
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzati.zzoW(Unknown Source:0)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatx.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaui.zzc(Unknown Source:0)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaue.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaui.zzMO(Unknown Source:0)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaue.zzbM(Unknown Source:0)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaub.onReceive(Unknown Source:0)
      at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver.onReceive(Unknown Source:0)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3091)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java:0)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1588)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

App Level Gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        applicationId "com.xxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 20005
        versionName "2.0.5"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:3.+'
    compile 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-fcm:3.+'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project level gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I soved my issue, now app is not crashing when download from play store.

Comment: Where solution is , is added permission in manifest      <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

Comment: can you share full manifest file. I'm having similar issues now

Answer (score 0):

Check out this multidex [mutidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle)
 and add this lib too

when using version 10.0.1 of the Firebase libs, you must use version 1.0.1 of Firebase UI:

```
  compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.1'
```

firebase UI [Firebase UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)